# Send Form data and Query string in one POST request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, query-string, multipartform-data

I need to send POST request through jmeter. I have checked the requests workflow through browser dev. tools. In my Post request I need to send form data and one string Query. Question is next - if i will add my string Query to URL will it work fine?
Example : somesite.com/something?refURL=someRef

Answer (score 0):

If it is a POST request, usually any form data will be sent in the request body. Not like a query string in the GET request. But the format is same.

`refURL=someRef` add this in the parameters section.

Check here for more info.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13

Comment: Ok so if i want to make Post request with both query string and form data should I add query string to path and form data to body (or to parameters)??

Look and the screenshot and tell me is it configured correct, please.

[Request](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hi1gom6mj63yfx5/Untitled112233.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Why not? Query string and request body are different beasts and they are processed differently on server side.

[image: JMeter Post with Query String]

Instead of asking this kind of questions, why don't you just record your test using [JMeter's proxy server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-superpower-http-proxy-server)?

References:

- [URI Syntax - Query Component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4)
- [HTTP Method Definitions - POST](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will.

You can even use variables like:

```
/some/path?refURL=${someCalculatedRefUrl}
```